# How do I display elements vertically using Java FX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a hashSet of a class of type Message with a working toString() method. The "refresh" button is correctly created, but there is an issue in its implementation.
Note:

```
//Menu is an ObservableList<String>
//Mymail contains the hashset
//refresh() is a method that adds a random message to the hashset
//GetMessages() returns the hashSet 
//the toString() method below is hashset's toString()

refresh.setOnAction(e -> {
    menu.setAll(myMail.refresh().getMessages().toString());
});
```

results in the following being printed in the window:
[image]

What should I do in order that the messages be displayed vertically like so:

```
"Message One Text"
"Message Two Text"
"Message Three Text"
```

Comment: Is the node, to which you are adding text, a `ListView`?

Comment: What kind of element is `menu`? Looks like a `ListView`?

Comment: Sorry about that. menu is an ObservableList<String>

Comment: and Menu is set to which node?

Comment: ListView<String> menuView = new ListView<String>(menu);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what we can guess, this should do the trick:

```
refresh.setOnAction(e -> menu.setAll(myMail.refresh().getMessages()));
```

Since `menu` is a `Collection` and can / should be added as one so each element gets added accordingly.

Edit: Second try:

```
refresh.setOnAction(e -> myMail.refresh().getMessages().stream().map(Message::toString).forEach(menu::add));
```

Comment: The following implementation is giving me the following error:                   "error: no suitable method found for setAll(HashSet<Message>)"

Answer (score 2):

You can [`addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html?is-external=true#addAll-java.util.Collection-) of the ObservableList:

```
refresh.setOnAction(e -> menu.addAll(myMail.refresh().getMessages()));
```

and use `toString` inside the Message, to convert message to String instead of using it in `Mymail`.

Comment: That is also giving me the same error as below. I'm not sure why, but  the error states that "no suitable method found for setAll(HashSet<Message>) ...HashSet<Message> cannot be converted to Collection